# How can i get the value of my input radio button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  state = {
    value1: "YES",
    value2: "NO",
    selectedRadioInput: "",
  };
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selectedRadioInput: e.target.value });
  }
        <div className="toggle_radio">
          <input
            type="radio"
            value={this.state.value1}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="toggle_option"
            id="first_toggle"
            name="toggle_option"
          />
          <input
            type="radio"
            value={this.state.value2}
            checked
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="toggle_option"
            id="second_toggle"
            name="toggle_option"
          />
          <label htmlFor="first_toggle">
            <p>YES</p>
          </label>
          <label htmlFor="second_toggle">
            <p>NO</p>
          </label>
          <div className="toggle_option_slider"></div>
          <h2>{this.state.selectedRadioInput}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have the following radio input button, on load the second button is checked.. I want to be able to get the value of my selected radio button.. pls help

Comment: Do you want the value on change or on load?

Comment: would want the value on change so everytime i change from yes to no or vice versa.. it updates the state value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

input elements should be [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in react, meaning the value of the input elements will be controlled by react. With controlled components, value of the input element is driven by react state.

This way, you can easily read the value of the radio inputs from the state of your component.

Following code snippet shows the value of the selected radio input.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value1: 'First Radio Button Value',
      value2: 'Second Radio Button Value',
      selectedRadioInput: '' 
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selectedRadioInput: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
            type="radio"
            value={this.state.value1}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="toggle_option"
            id="first-toggle"
            name="toggle_option"
          />
          <span>Radio Button 1</span>
          <br/>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value={this.state.value2}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="toggle_option"
            id="second_toggle"
            name="toggle_option"
          />
          <span>Radio Button 2</span>
          <h2>{this.state.selectedRadioInput}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here's the same code snippet with functional component instead of class based component

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    value1: 'First Radio Button Value',
    value2: 'Second Radio Button Value',
    selectedRadioInput: '' 
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setData({ ...data, selectedRadioInput: e.target.value });
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <input
            type="radio"
            value={data.value1}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="toggle_option"
            id="first-toggle"
            name="toggle_option"
          />
          <span>Radio Button 1</span>
          <br/>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value={data.value2}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="toggle_option"
            id="second_toggle"
            name="toggle_option"
          />
          <span>Radio Button 2</span>
          <h2>{data.selectedRadioInput}</h2>
      </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to compliment my code below tried to adjust it?, edited question

Comment: what's not working in your code? are you not able to see the value of the selected radio button?